# Replacing listview items with another list using combo box

Tags: vb.net, listview, combobox

Pardon for being novice at vb.net. I have a combo box and a list view. What I needed is when I change the category in the combo box and pressed 'OK', the old list added before will be replaced by a new list.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim i As ListViewItem

    If ComboBox1.Text = "Terrestrial Ecotoxicity (Freshwater)" Then

        i = ListView1.Items.Add("Water")
        i.SubItems.Add("2068.030567")
        i.SubItems.Add("0")
        i.SubItems.Add("0")

    ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "Terrestrial Ecotoxicity (Seawater)" Then

        i = ListView1.Items.Add("Dimethylamine")
        i.SubItems.Add("1229.539887")
        i.SubItems.Add("0.000122731")
        i.SubItems.Add("0.15090266")

    End if

End Sub
```

What should I need to add?

Comment: You didnt describe a problem or how that doesnt work but, if you want to ***replace*** the contents, dont you need to *clear* out the old first?  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: @Plutonix Sorry I'm just new here and had trouble finding solutions on search engines. By the way, whenever ListView1.Clear() inside if statements, nothing shows up after I press 'OK' button.

Comment: I know you are new: please read [Ask] and take the [tour]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing there is adding a different row on each case. What you ask is to fill the listview with different items depending on the item you pick at the combobox.

Basically, you need to clear the listview on each case. I'd do something like this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click 
    Dim i As ListViewItem

    ListView1.Items.Clear
    If ComboBox1.Text = "Terrestrial Ecotoxicity (Freshwater)" Then 
        i = ListView1.Items.Add("Water")      
        i.SubItems.Add("2068.030567") 
        i.SubItems.Add("0") 
        i.SubItems.Add("0") 
    ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "Terrestrial Ecotoxicity (Seawater)" Then 
        i = ListView1.Items.Add("Dimethylamine")
        i.SubItems.Add("1229.539887")
        i.SubItems.Add("0.000122731")
        i.SubItems.Add("0.15090266") 
    End if 
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you sir! Exactly what I needed.

Comment: My pleasure. Please mark the answer as correct if it is.